# Java script event to identify the UI is ready for user intraction

Tags: javascript, dom-events, pageload, page-load-time

I am working on a web application and have pages which gets data asynchronously using ajax call during the page load. These calls does not block the user. When we inspect the page using developer tools (IE and Chrome) it seems that the timing to load the entire page takes more than 26s. Please see the image attached which shows the details of default.aspx. But even before loading the entire page, the user can interact with page.

I need to find a way to identify at which point, the user can interact with page, using some java script event api like DOMContentLoaded. But I am not sure which event is the right one which ensures the user can start interacting with the page even if it is loading data in background using ajax call. Any guidance is appreciated

[image].

Comment: How about adding a blocker (like overlaying "Loading...") and remove the blocker in the _callback function_ of the AJAX call?

Comment: It is more like a performance test, and I am not supposed to change the code, instead i need to use/leverage some tools and capture the events and the timings